# Python + selenium webdriver Wait for popup window

Tags: python, selenium, popup, wait, unit-testing

After executing Autotest, it is crashed cause Pop-up window appears about 20 seconds. I need to wait until Pop-up loads and close it. If you start the following code you can see the Pop-up window.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    class FixInside(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_login_tensor(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://fix-inside.tensor.ru")
        driver.maximize_window()
        self.assertIn("Вход в систему/СБиС", driver.title)
        element = driver.find_element_by_id('fld-loginName')
        element.send_keys('check_rigth_user')
        element = driver.find_element_by_id('fld-loginPass')
        element.send_keys('qwerty123')
        login = driver.find_element_by_id('logButton')
        login.click()
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located('ws-fixed ws-window shadow radius ws-modal ws-window-draggable'))
        close_popup = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ws-window-titlebar-action close')
        close_popup.click()
```

Comment: I never used a `wait.until`, I usually use time.sleep(), but in your code there is some Russian characters, and I can't run your code successfully, so cant give you more help :-(

Comment: i can explain you Russian characters

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is this line:

```
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    'ws-fixed ws-window shadow radius ws-modal ws-window-draggable'))
```

which should be:

```
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 
    'ws-fixed ws-window shadow radius ws-modal ws-window-draggable')))
```

with import line:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: thank you,  i used your code but i have raise TimeoutException(message)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: